# dygraphs: y2 axis opposite direction

Tags: dygraphs

I want the y2 axis:

- only for visualisation (should not have any affects to the graph)
- begins with 0 at the red line (the data are always the same for red line. See the example)
- the count is opposite to the y1 axis

Example:
y2 axis

[image: 1]

The standard x2 axis affencts the graph an is not in opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can flip the y-axis with dygraphs by specifying the `valueRange` as `[max, min]` rather than the usual `[min, max]`. Here's an [example](https://dygraphs.com/tests/reverse-y-axis.html).

```js
const g = new Dygraph(
  el,
  data,
  {
    legend: 'always',
    axes: {
      y2: {
        valueRange: [14, 0],  // inverted range
      }
    },
    series: {
      'red': {
        axis: 'y2'  // plot red series on secondary y axis
      }
    }
  });
```

See [complete demo](https://jsbin.com/caqanowomo/edit?css,js,output).

Comment: Thanks. But I dont want to switch the axis. The data for both graphs are in the same scale. I only want the y2 achis for:          
1) only for visualisation (should not have any affects to the graph)
2) begins with 0 at the red line (the data are always the same for red line. See the example)

Comment: The data for the example-picture are:

"time,green,red\n" +
  "1,290,320\n" +
  "2,295,320\n" +
  "3,290,320\n" +
  "4,280,320\n" +
  "5,290,320\n",